# Zend framework 2 application in subdomain

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

Good day,
i have one Zend 2 application in shared host(www.mydomain.com). Now I need run new zend 2 application in sobdomain(www.subdomain.mydomain.com ).
I would not like to use shieldRoutes as are two applications without any dependencies. Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would define this in your nginx/apache configuration.  Define two separate domains, and point each host config to your separate apps.  It's very intuitive in the end, two separate apps, two configs - same approach for either.

Comment: This is new to me, how I can make this setting without access to vhost, send me reference files for I study this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Without having access to web server config, you're kind of up a creek if you're trying to keep things clean.  You don't want anything but /public being served.  Get in touch with your host and get them to create a separate zone for you, it's really the best way.